# Optimize Numpy extraction from multiband array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, vectorization, feature-extraction

I'm relatively new to python, so please correct me if "extraction" isn't the right terminology.

My problem : I'm working on image processing/analysis using Numpy, my code works fine but very slow with high resolutions.

this is a simplified case of what I want to do :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# Here i'm creating and example 6x6 image with 4 different bands.
band  = np.arange(1,37).reshape(6,6)
img = np.copy(band)
for i in range(1,4):
    img = np.dstack((img,band+i*100))
    
# Now creating the image segments, from which i'd like to extract pixel values
segments = np.kron( (np.arange(9)+1).reshape(3,3),np.ones((2,2)))
```

NOTE : In this example we have 9 square segments, but in practice there would be several thousands, with various shapes and sizes. (generated with the [Quickshift](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_segmentations.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-segmentations-py) methode)

```
plt.imshow(segments)

#Now my goal is, for each segment, to extract the pixel values ( all bands from img) under said segment.    
plt.imshow(segments==1)
# displaying only the first two bands for clarity.
print(A[:,:,0], A[:,:,1], sep="\n\n")
```

[image: This is what I mean by extracting pixel values]

```
#This is what it looks like for the first segment :
pixels = img[segments == 1]
pixels.T

array([[  1,   2,   7,   8],
       [101, 102, 107, 108],
       [201, 202, 207, 208],
       [301, 302, 307, 308]])
```

Now **This** is the part I want to optimize, Here I'm using a loop to get the pixel "under" each segment.

```
segment_ids = np.unique(segments)
segment_pixels = []

for i in segment_ids:
    pixels = img[ segments == i ]
    segment_pixels.append(pixels)
```

But, for very large images (> 2 Go), and lots of segments, this operation takes forever.
Is there a way to speed this up ?  I've read a bit about numpy vectorisation, but couldn't figure out how to apply it here.
Does anyone know how I could improve performances ?

Thank you !

Comment: if this is image processing, you need to learn about "masks". don't work with lists of indices if a mask does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting answer after clarification

You should have given us an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), more like this

```py
import numpy as np
# 4M pixels with 1k segments
img = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (2000, 2000))
segments = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (2000, 2000))
```

Then get the segments

```
%%time
segment_pixels = []
for i in np.unique(segments):
  segment_pixels.append(img[segments == i])
```

It takes about 5 seconds

If you don't mind using pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
```

It will take more memory but it provides a groupby function that is much faster than your approach if you have many groups and many records

```py
segment_pixels = pd.DataFrame({
  'segments': segments.reshape(-1), 
  'pixels': img.reshape(-1)
}).groupby('segments').groups
```

Runs in about `~330ms` where the previous aproach would take `~5s`

Comment: Thank's for the the answer, you cleverly took advantage of the kron product, but I used it for representing segments in a simple way, in practice, shapes and sizes would vary for each segments. I edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: Modifying only the first part, the computation of `img`, already gives a speedup (~90us per loop), because your call to stack in a loop create copies the array every iteration, this leads to quadratic complexity (but quadratic on size 4 for your example)